# "println needs a message" error in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read **Music_ID** of the group with **Playlist_ID** of **2** in firebase.

The following error occurs.

`java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`

This is my firebase realtime database.

[image]

And this is my code.

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

```
private void Startplaylist(String mood) {
        DatabaseReference plist = dref.child("Playlist");
        plist.orderByChild("Playlist_ID").equalTo(2).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Log.i("Value", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                String music_id = dataSnapshot.child("Music_ID").getValue(String.class);
                Log.i("Value_id", music_id);
                str_musictitle.setText(music_id);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

An alarm pops up that an error occurs in this part.
`Log.i("Value_id", music_id);`

I think "music_id" is not being read.

I tried to change part
`String music_id = dataSnapshot.child("Music_ID").getValue(String.class);`
to `String music_ids = dataSnapshot.child("Music_ID").getValue().toString();` and run it, but I couldn't get the desired result.

Comment: music_id is null.  You apparently can't log null.  The obvious thing I see is it's Music_ID in the db, and I believe it is case sensitive.

Comment: I modified it to ```String music_id = dataSnapshot.child("Music_ID").getValue(String.class); ```, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

The code in your `onDataChange` will need to handle this list by looping over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`. Something like this:

```
DatabaseReference plist = dref.child("Playlist");
plist.orderByChild("Playlist_ID").equalTo(2).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { //  Loop over results
            String music_id = snapshot.child("Music_ID").getValue(String.class); //  Get value for this result
            Log.i("Value_id", music_id);
            str_musictitle.setText(music_id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); //  Never ignore possible errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to you, Finally I solved it!!!